# Trying to get mysql sub string search working

Tags: mysql

I have a table with postcode districts such as SA1,SA3,SA11, LL41,NP20 and I need to do a search based upon a customer entering a postcode, and then matching the relevant record, i've tried :

```
SELECT MATCH(postal_district) AGAINST ('SA1 1EG') FROM `postcodes` WHERE MATCH(postal_district) AGAINST ('SA1 1EG') > 0
```

but it returns nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you perhaps want to do something more like this?

```
SELECT postal_district FROM postcodes WHERE  MATCH(postal_district) AGAINST('SA1 1EG' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I'm not sure a fulltext search is what you really want, either way, as you'd possibly be better served having one code per row and just doing a case-insensitive match (just compare the upper-case'd version of each).  If you insist on using the above, make sure you have a fulltext index on the column you're searching against (postal_district).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but did you mean this...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `postcodes` WHERE MATCH(postal_district) AGAINST ('SA1 1EG');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `postcodes` WHERE postal_district LIKE '%SA1%'
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here.  If you could try to clarify a little.

Answer (score 0):

The typical syntax for fulltext search in MySQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM postcodes
WHERE MATCH (postal_district) AGAINST ('SA1 1EG');
```

Full text search is on only if you add a FULLTEXT index to the column.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html